# RecyclerView is not showing up at all. I cannot find the error. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to build my recyclerview into multiple fragments using a ViewPageAdapter. I'm pretty new to Android Studio, and I don't know how to approach the error I'm getting. My recyclerview is not showing up, and while running, the only problem that I seem to be having is a "skipping frames" type of issue. This is usually less than 100 frames(and my emulator is slow, so I don't know if the application is actually taking up so much time).

Things I have tried to fix it: I have tried using an AsyncTask class, but I am still unsure how to properly implement it if it was slowing down the application. Some people on this platform suggested that you need to flip the order in which the recycler view adapter and the layout manager are set, but this hasn't been helping out at all.

Note: I haven't had time to create new fragment classes for the ViewPageAdapter. There is only one fragment class currently, but I intend on the ViewPager to have multiple fragments represented as multiple pages. (Also, I don't want to share the overall idea behind my team's project. I would like to keep this subtly anonymous, but if you find it necessary to understand what's the main idea of the project, I can definitely send a message for further details.)

Fragment where I set the RecyclerView Adapter

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Fragment_new extends Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private List<new_prescription> list_prescriptions;

    public View onCreateNewView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);
        myRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_obj);
        recyclerViewAdapter recycleAdapter = new recyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), list_prescriptions);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        list_prescriptions = new ArrayList<>();
        list_prescriptions.add(new new_prescription("Some Medication #1", "6:30-9:30", 5));
        list_prescriptions.add(new new_prescription("Some Medication #2", "1:30-4:30", 5));
    }
}
```

ViewPageAdapter to create views for different fragments

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private final List<Fragment> pager_list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String>   string_List = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return pager_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return string_List.size();
    }

    public CharSequence elementString(int position) {
        return string_List.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        pager_list.add(fragment);
        string_List.add(title);

    }


}
```

An Ordinary RecyclerViewAdapter for my RecyclerView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class recyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context data;
    List<new_prescription> new_list;

    public recyclerViewAdapter(Context data, List<new_prescription> new_list) {
        this.data = data;
        this.new_list = new_list;
    }

    public recyclerViewAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(data).inflate(R.layout.new_fragment_items, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder view = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.new_name.setText(new_list.get(position).getName());
        holder.new_quantity.setText(new_list.get(position).getTime());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return new_list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView new_name;
        private TextView new_quantity;
        private ImageView new_image;
        private TextView  new_time;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            new_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prescription_name);
            new_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_image);
            new_quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_items);
            new_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_time);

        }

    }
    }
```

Main Activity Class

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class Main_Activity_Frags extends AppCompatActivity {

   private TabLayout layout;
   private ViewPager viewpager;
   private ViewPageAdapter adapter;


   public Main_Activity_Frags() {
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);

       layout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_id);
       viewpager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
       adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


       adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_new(),"Prescriptions For Today");
       adapter.addFragment(new Secondary_Fragment(),"Quantity");
       adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_final(), "Time");


       viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
       layout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
       layout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_today_black_18dp);
       layout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_history_black_18dp);


   }



}
```

This is the class that I am using to instantiate new_prescription objects that are added to the RecyclerView Arraylist.

```
public class new_prescription {

    private String Name;
    private String Time;
    private int Frequency;

    public new_prescription() {
    }

    public new_prescription(String name, String time, int frequency) {
        Name = name;
        Time = time;
        Frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return Frequency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's work, try this:

```
public class Fragment_new extends Fragment {

            private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
            private List<new_prescription> list_prescriptions;


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);
                myRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_obj);
                list_prescriptions = new ArrayList<>();
                list_prescriptions.add(new new_prescription("Some Medication #1", "6:30-9:30", 5));
                list_prescriptions.add(new new_prescription("Some Medication #2", "1:30-4:30", 5));

                recyclerViewAdapter recycleAdapter = new recyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), list_prescriptions);
                myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                myRecyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);
                return v;

            }


        }
```

Comment: It's not working. I am getting this when running.  "Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."